# Вычисление суммы ряда в матрице

Tags: python

Нужно посчитать сумму ряда в матрице. Того ряда, который вводит пользователь. Не могу придумать, как это сделать...(

```
import random
random.seed()
m = input('Количество столбцов > ') # количество столбцов
n = input('Количество строк > ') # количество рядов
print()
M = [[random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(int(m))] for _ in range(int(n))]
for V in M:
    for e in V:
        print(e, end=', ')
    print()

even = 0
for V in M:
    for e in V:
        if e % 2 == 0:
            even += 1

print()
print('Количество чётных элементов: {chet}'.format(chet = even))

summline = 0
NumberLine = input(print('Введите номер ряда, сумму которого Вы хотите узнать > '))
```

Comment: Функция `sum` есть готовая. Можно и просто сложить в цикле.

Comment: А в каком цикле?

Comment: В цикле for, например, таком же, как сейчас `if e % 2 == 0:` делается

Comment: Да, я это понимаю. Но я не понимаю как это реализовать. Типа, как именно в том ряде, номер которого введет пользователь, вычислить сумму?(

Comment: Написал в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `numpy`:

Задаем матрицу

```
import numpy as np
m=10 #строки
n=15 #столбцы
row = 7 #ряд, сумму которого нужно узнать

mt = np.random.randint(-100, high=100, size=(m,n))
print(mt)

[[ 29 -81 -62 -64 -37  28  68  54  62  32 -85 -45   6  43 -93]
 [ 99  66  72 -78 -78 -26  94 -74  65 -96 -35  65   1 -66 -63]
 [ 42 -86 -53  93  61  48 -12  69  34  45   3 -21 -20  89 -55]
 [-59  93  90 -18 -39 -82 -59  55   9  63  94 -26  27 -19  29]
 [-62  -2  76  86 -36 -92  63  83 -23  29  63 -44 -90   4   4]
 [  7   3  22  19 -24  98  92 -53  85  33 -16 -80  97  -9 -45]
 [  0  31  62  17  73 -37 -78  18  41  57  68  38 -75  47  53]
 [-46 -69  -9   0  43  91  -6  97 -90 -57  41 -39  89  77  52]
 [ 41 -23  58  17 -74  29 -40 -59 -19  76  25  31  36  33 -69]
 [  4   3 -98  37  24  17  86  14  12  97  76  52  49  37 -51]]
```

Собственно, решение:

```
print(mt.sum(axis=1)[row])
```

Результат:

```
174
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberLine = int(input(print('Введите номер ряда, сумму которого Вы хотите узнать > ')))

print("sum = ", sum(M[NumberLine]))
```

или (использование sum предпочтительно)

```
summline = 0
for e in M[NumberLine]:
        summline += e
print(summline)
```

Пример вывода

```
Количество столбцов > 3
Количество строк > 3

-85, 6, 22, 
-79, 34, 65, 
-29, -65, 20, 

Количество чётных элементов: 4
Введите номер ряда, сумму которого Вы хотите узнать > 
1
sum =  20
20
```

Comment: Вычисления не происходят правильно, почему-то(

Comment: Вот я привёл пример, всё правильно